# Find some value in a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read every line in one sheet (Get_Command) and looking for the value in the first column in an another sheet (Command_List); if this value is in the Command_List I want to copy the line (deleting some columns) to a third sheet (Set_Command).

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim fnFormat As Range
Dim c As Long
Dim MyCol As Long
Dim fCommand As Range
Dim Command As String

With Sheets("Get_Command")
.Select

 Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For Lrow = 1 To Lastrow Step 1

Command = Cells(Lrow, 1).Value

    Set fCommand = Worksheets("Command_List").Columns("A:A").Find(Command, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not fCommand Is Nothing Then

            Lastcolumn = .Cells(Lrow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                Range("A" & Lrow).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Set_Command").Select
                Range("A" & Lrow).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Replace What:="Get:", Replacement:="Set", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Sheets("Get_Command").Select

                Set fnFormat = Range(Cells(Lrow, 5), Cells(Lrow, Lastcolumn)).Find("nFormat", LookIn:=xlValues)

                    If fnFormat Is Nothing Then 'If it is not found

                        c = 1

                        For Lcolumn = 5 To Lastcolumn Step 2

                            Cells(Lrow, Lcolumn).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Sheets("Set_Command").Select
                            c = c + 1
                            Cells(Lrow, c).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Sheets("Get_Command").Select

                        Next Lcolumn

                    Else

                        c = 1

                        'It should remove "(", ")", "," and the columns that a don't need

                        For Lcolumn = 5 To fnFormat.Column - 3 Step 2
                            Cells(Lrow, Lcolumn).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Sheets("Set_Command").Select
                            c = c + 1
                            Cells(Lrow, c).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Sheets("Get_Command").Select

                        Next Lcolumn

                        For Lcolumn = fnFormat.Column + 3 To Lastcolumn Step 2
                            Cells(Lrow, Lcolumn).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Sheets("Set_Command").Select
                            c = c + 1
                            Cells(Lrow, c).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Sheets("Get_Command").Select

                        Next Lcolumn

                    End If

        End If

Next Lrow

End With

End Sub
```

The problem is on:

```
Command = Cells(Lrow, 1).Value

    Set fCommand = Worksheets("Command_List").Columns("A:A").Find(Command, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

The Command is saving what I want, but fCommand is returning always Nothing.

Could someone help me to find my error?

Thanks! =)

Comment: Add "Option Explicit" at the top of your module and compile. I found four undefined variables.  I was able to get the existing code (after defining variables) to write to the 'Set_Command' sheet

Comment: Some variables are defined outside, that why is not showing there! =) Probably you found Lastrow, Lastcolumn, Lrow, Lcolumn right?

Comment: Exactly. But my simple test of four rows always returned a value where you got Nothing.  Can you clarify what you mean by: "The Command is saving what I want, but fCommand is returning always Nothing"? After each 'Set fCommand', I have a value in 'fCommand'

Comment: The variables "Command" is saving the Value that I have in Cells (Lrow, 1), but when I go to the line below, it is not reading this value in the "Command_List" Sheet, so it fCommand is return Nothing, even if I have this value in the "Command_List", I don't know if I could explain on a good way!

Comment: How about posting several lines of examples of text you have in col A of both sheets.

Comment: I saw that, maybe the problem is: it's reading just the first cell in Command_List, and not all column.. But I'll put some examples to show what I'm trying to do! =)

Comment: Why this `.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row` and not that `.UsedRange.Rows.Count`?

Comment: The problem was really at Command_List, it was with a different format! =/ I don't believe that. But thanks a lot Wayne G. Dunn for you atention! =)

Answer (score 0):

Find returns Nothing when it does not find a matchin cell. So you have problem with the data that you are using. Potential source for your problem:

- there are leading or trailing spaces in your command or in the list of possible commands
- you are referencing the wrong range in Find